# Round corners ItemDecoration

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-canvas, android-view, android-custom-view

I have a `RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager` that contains items with various `ViewTypes` (and `SpanSize`s as well). I need to round corners for all `R.layout.item_image` types as on the picture below

[image: Round corners example]

So I've created an `ItemDecoration` that calculates the `Rect` on which these items will be drawn. And then clips the `Canvas` to this `Rect` (use `Path` to round corners):

```
public class RoundCornersDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {
    private final float radius;
    private final RectF defaultRectToClip;

    public RoundCornersDecoration(float radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
        defaultRectToClip = new RectF(Float.MAX_VALUE, Float.MAX_VALUE, 0, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        final RectF rectToClip = getRectToClip(parent);

        // has no items with ViewType == `R.layout.item_image`
        if (rectToClip.equals(defaultRectToClip)) {
            return;
        }

        final Path path = new Path();
        path.addRoundRect(rectToClip, radius, radius, Path.Direction.CW);
        canvas.clipPath(path);
    }

    private RectF getRectToClip(RecyclerView parent) {
        final RectF rectToClip = new RectF(defaultRectToClip);
        final Rect childRect = new Rect();
        for (int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++) {
            if (!isImage(parent, i)) {
                continue;
            }

            final View child = parent.getChildAt(i);
            parent.getDecoratedBoundsWithMargins(child, childRect);

            rectToClip.left = Math.min(rectToClip.left, childRect.left);
            rectToClip.top = Math.min(rectToClip.top, childRect.top);
            rectToClip.right = Math.max(rectToClip.right, childRect.right);
            rectToClip.bottom = Math.max(rectToClip.bottom, childRect.bottom);
        }
        return rectToClip;
    }

    private boolean isImage(RecyclerView parent, int viewPosition) {
        final RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = parent.getAdapter();
        final int viewType = adapter.getItemViewType(viewPosition);
        return viewType == R.layout.item_image;
    }
}
```

And everything is ok except **no other items are drawn below the images**.
I guess that's because I clip the canvas *before* any items are actually drawn. So how should I clip the canvas in order to save round corners and diplay all other items?

Comment: in `onCreateViewHolder` you create your root `View` and `ViewHolder` - use a custom `FrameLayout` as your "root view" and override its `dispatchDraw` method - there you can clip your canvas and all the child views will be clipped as well

Comment: @pskink if I got you right then I need to check the order of views there (e.g. to clip the top-left corner, or to clip the bottom-right corner)

Comment: yes, inside `onBindViewHolder` you have `int position` so you can check if its top or middle or bottom view and change the path acordingly

Comment: @pskink then it would be simpler not to clip but to set a background with a proper `<corners .. />` shape to the root `View`. Any way I don't want to expose that logic into a `ViewHolder` because I reuse it in many places. So I'm looking for a way to solve it via an `ItemDecoration`.
But thanks for the advice. I'll use that if I have no other choice.

Comment: you dont touch your `ViewHolder`s - all you need is to pass a root `View` that clips their child views

Comment: @pskink can you post an answer (with code), plz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found a solution and it's quite simple. All I need to do is to provide **the other part** of the `canvas`:

[image: pic]

As you can see *top*, *left* and *right* points are the same as for the first rect so we need to find only the *bottom*:

```
    int maxBottom = 0;
    final Rect childRect = new Rect();
    for (int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++) {
        final View child = parent.getChildAt(i);
        parent.getDecoratedBoundsWithMargins(child, childRect);
        maxBottom = Math.max(maxBottom, childRect.bottom);
    }
```

Create a new rect:

```
    final RectF otherItemsRect = new RectF(rectToClip);
    otherItemsRect.top = otherItemsRect.bottom;
    otherItemsRect.bottom = maxBottom;
```

Include it into the `Path` and then clip:

```
    final Path path = new Path();
    path.addRoundRect(rectToClip, radius, radius, Path.Direction.CW);
    path.addRect(otherItemsRect, Path.Direction.CW);
    canvas.clipPath(path);
```

That's it. Now we have all the items with round corners for images

P.S. I don't provide an optimized code here in order of simplicity

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on this and show how you structured the above code ^

Comment: Also, is there an error in the "Create a new rect" part ?

Comment: @VinayGaba You can find the final version in this gist: https://gist.github.com/NikolayKul/67450c10d443fe680f73f896211a7d3d

Comment: There's no error in "Create a new rect" part. It's just a shorter version of this:

```RectF otherItemsRect = new RectF();
otherItemsRect.top = rectToClip.bottom;
otherItemsRect.left = rectToClip.left;
otherItemsRect.right = rectToClip.right;
otherItemsRect.bottom = maxBottom;```

Comment: My bad, I was able to understand your logic later :) Thanks!

Comment: I tried this but the corners are a bit choppy, they're not smooth. Any idea how can it be fixed?